# Python Data-wrangling

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in Python below:

```
print (df)
         Date  Hour  Weight
0  2019-01-01     8       1
1  2019-01-01    16       2
2  2019-01-01    24       6
3  2019-01-02     8      10
4  2019-01-02    16       4
5  2019-01-02    24      12
6  2019-01-03     8      10
7  2019-01-03    16       6
8  2019-01-03    24       5
```

How can I create a column (New_Col) that will return me the value of 'Hour' for the lowest value of 'Weight' in the day. I'm expecting:

```
Date       Hour  Weight New_Col
2019-01-01  8    1      8
2019-01-01  16   2      8
2019-01-01  24   6      8
2019-01-02  8    10     16 
2019-01-02  16   4      16
2019-01-02  24   12     16
2019-01-03  8    10     24
2019-01-03  16   6      24
2019-01-03  24   5      24
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin.html), but first create index by `Hour` column for values from `Hour` per minimal `Weight` per groups:

```
df['New'] = df.set_index('Hour').groupby('Date')['Weight'].transform('idxmin').values
print (df)
         Date  Hour  Weight  New_Col  New
0  2019-01-01     8       1        8    8
1  2019-01-01    16       2        8    8
2  2019-01-01    24       6        8    8
3  2019-01-02     8      10       16   16
4  2019-01-02    16       4       16   16
5  2019-01-02    24      12       16   16
6  2019-01-03     8      10       24   24
7  2019-01-03    16       6       24   24
8  2019-01-03    24       5       24   24
```

Alternative solution:

```
df['New'] = df['Date'].map(df.set_index('Hour').groupby('Date')['Weight'].idxmin())
```

Comment: All your codes just return 8, so your `print(df)` output is misleading.

Comment: @cs95 - ya, unfornately first and second sample data are different. I first cannot find problem why all values are 8, but then I notice it.

Comment: I came up with this answer before you had posted anything it but I refrained from posting because the data was wrong. Sometimes the best action is to not answer. Just my 2c. Better inform OP so they can fix it first.

Comment: Ya, created solution and 3 minutes find problem, then found it, so post answer.